# Multithreading of For loop in python

Tags: python

I am creating some scripts to help my database import while using docker. I currently have a directory filled with data, and I want to import as quickly as possibly.

All of the work done is all single threaded, so I wanted to speed things up by passing off multiple jobs at once to each thread on my server.

This is done by this code I've written.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess

cities = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

for x in cities:
    dockerscript = "docker exec -it worker_1 perl import.pl ./public/%s %s mariadb" % (x,x)
    p = subprocess.Popen(dockerscript, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This works fine if I have more than 10 cores, each gets its own. What I want to do is set it up, so if I have 4 cores, the first 4 iterations of the dockerscript runs, 1 to 4, and 5 to 10 wait.

Once any of the 1 to 4 completes,  5 is started and so on until it is all completed.

I am just having a harder time figuring out how to do this is python

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John already has the answer but there are a couple of subtleties worth mentioning. A thread pool is fine for this application because the thread just spends its time blocked waiting for the subprocess to terminate. And you can use `map` with `chunksize=1` so the pool goes back to the parent to fetch a new job on each iteration.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess
import multiprocessing.pool

cities = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

def run_docker(city):
    return subprocess.call(['docker', 'exec', '-it', 'worker_1', 'perl',
        'import.pl', './public/{0}'.format(city), city, 'mariadb'])

pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool()
results = pool.map(run_docker, cities, chunksize=1)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: So between Johns answer, what is the map, and chunksize=1 doing that just using mutiprocessing.Pool() doesn't accomplish?

Comment: You can use `multiprocessing.Pool` equally well, except that it has more overhead. For linux, its a `fork` and for windows its an exec of a new python process plus pickling of the context needed to run. Then input/output needs to be piped between processes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `multiprocessing.Pool()` which will automatically create one process per core, then submit your jobs to it.  Each job will be a function which calls `subprocess` to start Docker.  Note that you need to make sure the jobs are synchronous--i.e. the Docker command must not return before it is done working.

Comment: With using mutiprocessing.Pool() is this really just a replacement line for subprocess.Popen()? The for loop "for x in cities" all stays the same.